# Not able to open MonoDevelop v 2.4.2

Tags: mono, osx-snow-leopard, monodevelop

When I try to open MonoDevelop this error appears in the console log

```
com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[249] ([0x0-0x13013].com.ximian.monodevelop[308]) Exited with exit code: 255
```

How can I fix the problem?

**EDIT:** Snow Leopard 10.6.8, MonoDevelop 2.4.2 and Mono 2.10.5.

**UPDATE:** This is the error if I try to run MonoDevelop from shell

```
LSOpenURLsWithRole() failed with error -10810 for the file /Applications/MonoDevelop.app.
```

**UPDATE 2:** I've found the crash reporter for mono

```
FATAL ERROR [2011-09-03 15:06:25Z]: MonoDevelop failed to start. Some of the assemblies required to run MonoDevelop (for example gtk-sharp, gnome-sharp or gtkhtml-sharp) may not be properly installed in the GAC.
System.DllNotFoundException: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/2.10.5/lib/libgtk-quartz-2.0.0.dylib
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) Gtk.Application:gtk_init (int&,intptr&)
  at Gtk.Application.do_init (System.String progname, System.String[]& args, Boolean check) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Gtk.Application.Init (System.String progname, System.String[]& args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Ide.IdeStartup.Run (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at MonoDevelop.Startup.MonoDevelopMain.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Any help?

Comment: Can you please share more information about your system? Especially OS version and Mono version. Also, is this the full output if you run it from a terminal?

Comment: Is this really the complete output yo get when you run MonoDevelop from a console?

Comment: sorry, it's the output from the console log. How is it possible to run MonoDevelop from the console? Thank you.

Comment: Ahm...I have no idea how exactly that works on MacOS...well, look at the properties of the starter for that.

Comment: Thanks for coming back with your solution. Please don't put in in your question, instead post it as an answer (it's [allowed, and even encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), when you figure things out on your own).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those interested in:

1. Uninstall Mono with this script [uninstall script](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono%3aOSX#Uninstalling_Mono_on_Mac_OS_X). You have to save the script in a file with extension .sh
2. Save the file in the desktop as uninstallMonoFr.sh (for example)
3. Open a terminal window: cd Desktop, sudo ./uninstallMonoFr.sh, insert your pwd
4. Download mono framework 2.10.4 (this version works for me)
5. Install again

I don't know if the problem is due to 2.10.5 version of mono framework. 2.10.4 works well.

**UPDATE** Seems that Mono 2.10.5 still presenting a package bug. MonoDevelop can't open with this version. Mono 2.10.4 works.

**UPDATE  2** I've just installed **2.10.6** and it works. MonoDevelop now opens correctly.

Comment: First, fix the uppercase (I don't feel like doing that for you). Second, no need to write `Solution` over an answer...answers are normally the solution to questions (especially if you accept them as anwer). Otherwise a +1.

Answer (score 0):

This also helped me (permission issue):

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/277759/cannot-start-built-in-monodevelop.html

I just added myself (user) with read&write permissions.